# Typescript property does not exist on type Element

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have tried to add a declaration file and a few other things but nothing is working so far:

I basically want to set `visible` to be a function on the HTML `Element` object. This is what I have and the linter has `visible` underlined saying `Property 'visible' does not exist on type 'Element'`. What am I doing wrong?

```
Element.prototype.visible = function() {
  return (!window.getComputedStyle(this)
    || window.getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue('display') == ''
    || window.getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue('display') != 'none')
}
```

I'm using Typescript 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [augment global declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html):

```
export {};

declare global {
    interface Element {
        visible: () => boolean;
    }
}

Element.prototype.visible = function() {
    return (!window.getComputedStyle(this)
        || window.getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue('display') == ''
        || window.getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue('display') != 'none')
};
```

---

`export {};` is used to make this file a module. If you already have any other exports or imports - you don't need this